# Display a notification on form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am currently working on an application that displays clients in a DataGridView. By right clicking the user can delete the client from the grid, show more detailed information or put the client into a ListBox for later use without having to scroll through the whole grid again.
If the selected client is already in the ListBox, it won't be added a second time.
This is working fine so far, but I don't want my application to just do nothing at all when the user tries to store a client a second time.
I want the form to show a small text notification close to the mouse cursor that says something like "client is already in the list" and automatically goes away after one second.
Sadly I could only find balloon notifications and a tutorial for notifications for Microsoft Service.

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (item.Text)
    {
        case "Show detailed info":
            // Shows detailed info
            break;
        case "Store client for later":
            var c = ClientFactory.GetClient(ClientView.CurrentRow)
            if (listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Any(mandant => mandant.ToString() == m.ToString()))
            {
                // Something like Notification.Show();
                return;
            }
        case "Delete client":
            // Deletes client
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest fix would be to disable (not hide) the button when the client is already stored, along with a tooltip (which I believe should still show, even if the button is disabled) that explains WHY it's disabled.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I don't have a button though, I'm using a ContextMenutStrip.

Comment: then disable the corresponding MenuStripItem for that entry

Comment: Added code to show how stuff works. The program checks if the client is already stored after the MenuStripItem for that action is clicked.

Comment: Do u want to show the notification near a button or some other control or near the Cursor no matter where the Cursor is

Comment: @Sybren I was planning on showing it near the cursor.

Comment: Get the cursor position then and use a timer to show/hide the label

Comment: @Wilsu As Marco says, disable the MenuStripItem, and add a tooltip to the disabled item. This will need to be checked on the displaying of the Context Menu, so it will be evaluated every time you rightclick.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard Alright. Though I'm still sceptical because creating an object and comparing it to the other objects in the ListBox seems like a lot of stuff to do for something that probably won't even happen...

Comment: Such is the life of a developer. At least when developing consumer products. Sometimes you have to handle cases that will likely never happen, because the user would have to use the application in a completely obscure and unreasonable way. But you have to handle it. By handle, I just mean something like showing a message that says "You can't do it THIS way, but THIS other way is how to do it"

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't complaining about having to write the code - I'd have to write it anyways, just somewhere else - but the fact that the program is doing work it doesn't have to do (yet). But well, it's still just one object and a handful of compare operations, can't make a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @Wilsu: could you wrap your edit as an answer, please? This way everyone will see the question is answered already, and anyone with the same problem will be able to find it.

Comment: @DeFazer Done, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**
 In the end I did the following:

- Moved existing item detection from contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked to ClientView_CellMouseClick, which gets called when the user right clicks on the grid
- Disabled the MenuStripItem to store clients
- Set its ToolTipText property to "Client already in the list"

Works like a charm.

Thanks to Bjarke for his time.